# Extract first not NA value from selected columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to extract the first non NA value from a set of columns. "First" is defined by the order of columns. Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- tribble(~a, ~x, ~w, ~z,
              "s", NA, 1, 2,
              "m", 2, 3, 0,
              "k", 9, NA, NA,
              "o", NA, NA, 4,
              "z", NA, NA, NA)
```

That is a not working option - because it only extracts 2 & 9:

```
d1 %>%
  mutate(want = pmap_int(list(x, w, z), ~.x[!is.na(.x)][1] ))
```

Want is: `1, 2, 9, 4, NA`.

Comment: d1 %>%  mutate(want=do.call(coalesce,across(c(-a))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::coalesce` you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 |> 
  mutate(want = coalesce(x, w, z))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   a         x     w     z  want
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 s        NA     1     2     1
#> 2 m         2     3     0     2
#> 3 k         9    NA    NA     9
#> 4 o        NA    NA     4     4
#> 5 z        NA    NA    NA    NA
```